# Is FreeResource required on 64-bit?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

According to afxv_w32.h, FreeResource and UnlockResource are not required on Win32 platforms (see last line of this file). What about Win64 platforms? I guess this remark also applies on these platforms. Can anyone confirm this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeResource on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648044%28VS.85%29.aspx) says no. The function was used in 16bit windows, and is no longer required afterwards, which includes 64bit.